# Glew+GLFW Win32 No Dependencies Visual Studio

Tags: c++, opengl, glew, glfw

Is it possible to build and link Glew and GLFW without copying files to the C:??

I can't find any documentation that shows how to use these libraries without copying DLLs to the Visual Studio Directory on the C:.

I just want to include all the .dll and .lib files needed in the directory of my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to put the DLLs in Visual Studio Directory .You can drop those in the Debug or Release (based on your compile mode) folder of your VS project.And you do have to include those DLLs.The rest of setup is rather simple.Right click your project and select **"Properties"**.Include the headers of both libs under **C/C++** --> **"Additonal Include Directories"** . Then : **Linker** --> **"Additional Library Directories"** you include the folders containing the lib files.And lastly under **Linker**-->**Input**-->**"Additional Dependencies"** add the names of glew and GLFW libs (**glew32.lib** , **GLFW.lib**)And you are ready to go.

Comment: You can do this; but a `#pragma comment (lib, "glew32.lib")` somewhere in the source is probably the better way to go than embedding this in project files.

Comment: .. or make an external_libs folder containing all headers, libs and DLLs for easy access. DLLs are found through the PATH env variable, so you can override PATH if you open your project from a separate terminal. Env variables are only passed in when VC opens.

Comment: Important note here is "#pragma comment" is Microsoft C++ specific.It won't work with other compilers if you decide move the project outside MS world :)

Comment: After all these steps, the project compiled successfully. but I got `error LNK2019` when running. I added lib path to **Linker --> "Additional Library Directories"**, added glew32s.lib to **Linker-->Input-->"Additional Dependencies"**, and copied glew32.dll under project/debug folder. What's wrong with it?