# Glut error when compiling in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opengl, compiler-construction

I'm trying to compile a C++ opengl project inside Visual Studio but I'm getting the following errors :

```
Error   2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp____glutInitWithExit@12 referenced in function _glutInit_ATEXIT_HACK@8
Error   2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp____glutInitWithExit@12 referenced in function _glutInit_ATEXIT_HACK@8
Error   4   error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
```

Does anyone know why I'm getting this error? Am I missing a library?

Comment: From looking on Google, either linking to `glut32.lib` or using `#define GLUT_DISABLE_ATEXIT_HACK`.

Comment: make sure you have you project setup as described here but replace GLFW with GLUT stuff. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13785633/glewglfw-win32-no-dependencies-visual-studio

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19401441

Answer (score 0):

GLUT is too old library. Using FreeGlut to replace GLUT. The APIs is same and you can find it by [here](http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/).

In windows platform:

- download the source code
- select the right vs solution file and build it.
- copy the dll file to c:\windows\system32
- copy the lib file to VisualStudioInstalledDirectory\VC\lib or C:\Program Files\windows kit\8.*\Lib\winv6.3\um\x86
- copy the header files to VisualStudioInstalledDirectory\VC\include\GL or C:\Program Files\windows kit\8.*\Include\um\gl

Now, after `#include <GL/freeglut.h>` you can use glut functions