# Cant compile any opengl/freeglut/glut source code

Tags: c++, opengl

I have this code which i took from an opengl example code:

```
#include <GL/glut.h>

// Display callback ------------------------------------------------------------

void display()
{
    // clear the draw buffer .
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);   // Erase everything

    // set the color to use in draw
    glColor3f(0.5, 0.5, 0.0);       
    // create a polygon ( define the vertexs) 
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON); {           
        glVertex2f(-0.5, -0.5);
        glVertex2f(-0.5,  0.5);
        glVertex2f( 0.5,  0.5);
        glVertex2f( 0.5, -0.5);
    } glEnd();

    // flush the drawing to screen . 
    glFlush(); 
}

// Keyboard callback function ( called on keyboard event handling )
void keyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
    if (key == 'q' || key == 'Q')
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

// Main execution  function 
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);      // Initialize GLUT
    glutCreateWindow("OpenGL example");  // Create a window
    glutDisplayFunc(display);   // Register display callback
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard); // Register keyboard callback
    glutMainLoop();             // Enter main event loop

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

it should work right?
but when i run it:

```
Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glutMainLoop@0 referenced in function _main    C:\Users\Naor\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\test\test\Source.obj    test
Error   2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glutKeyboardFunc@4 referenced in function _main    C:\Users\Naor\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\test\test\Source.obj    test
Error   3   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glutDisplayFunc@4 referenced in function _main C:\Users\Naor\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\test\test\Source.obj    test
Error   4   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp____glutInitWithExit@12 referenced in function _glutInit_ATEXIT_HACK@8   C:\Users\Naor\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\test\test\Source.obj    test
Error   5   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp____glutCreateWindowWithExit@8 referenced in function _glutCreateWindow_ATEXIT_HACK@4    C:\Users\Naor\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\test\test\Source.obj    test
Error   6   error LNK1120: 5 unresolved externals   C:\Users\Naor\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\test\Debug\test.exe 1   1   test
```

I installed opengl, freeglut correctly (i mean, it runs and vc++ find's it no problem),
but i cant run any source code i find.. (same error's)

Comment: Looks like you need to set some linker dependencies in your project properties

Comment: Add glut32.lib to the linker settings.

Comment: Its cant find glut32.lib, maybe something else? 
thanks.

Comment: So you installed glut - find its .lib or .dll file in filesystem, then point linker dependencies in IDE to that file exactly.

Comment: consult exact linker settings here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13785633/  but use glut library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer, to anyone who have this kind of issue check these:

1. You linked your lib and include correctly. (32bit is recommended, fixed my error).
2. After you've done this, you'll probably get an error that it cant open or find some dll file.
3. Check what dll it is (in the error message), copy it where your exe is located (for debug mode to the Debug folder, and release to the Release folder).

Hope that fixed your error :)